# gvim 3 way merge guess from visual studio

Tags: vim, merge

*Is there any way to get gvim to automatically build the merge file using it's best guess?*

I have configured 3 way merge on visual studio 2012 as follows.
gvim -f -d -c "wincmd J" "$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"
(Replacing the relevant $NAME with 1,2,3 etc).

I now have all the windows displaying as they should, but the merged file is blank.
Is there any way to get gvim to automatically build the merge file using it's best guess?
I can then manually check that the merges are correct.

Here is a nice reference article: http://www.toofishes.net/blog/three-way-merging-git-using-vim/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim has built-in functionality to interpret diffs and visualize them. It has no functionality to reconcile or merge differences. Of course, its underlying *Vimscript* is a fully-fledged programming language, so such could be implemented, but I'd rather look for a version control tool to provide this, as this is part of the main functionality of such tools (but not text editors).

Comment: I thought as much. I was hoping there was a plugin (or command line tool) that would do the merge.